# Django view decoding danish chars from CSV

Tags: python, django, csv

I have a csv file that contains some strange (incorrect) encoded danish characters (å-ø-æ). In my Django view I'm trying to grab a string from the first row, and the date from the second row in the file. The file looks like this if I copy paste it.

```
01,01,Project Name: SAM_LOGIK_rsm¿de_HD,,,Statistics as of: Sat Oct 01 17:09:16 2016
02,01,Project created: Tue Apr 12 09:10:16 2016,,,Last Session Started: Sat Oct 01 16:59:22 2016
```

The string *SAM_LOGIK_rsm¿de_HD* should be *SAM_LOGIK_Årsmøde_HD* - which is the value I want to store in the DB.

I am decoding the file with iso-8859-1 (otherwise I get an error).

```
with open(latest, 'rt', encoding='iso-8859-1') as csvfile:
        for i, row in enumerate(csvfile):
            if "Project Name:" in row:
                this = row.split(',')
                project_list.append(this[2][14:]) # gets the project name as is
                if i >= 1:
                    break
            else:
                this = row.split(',')
                date = datetime.strptime(this[5][22:-1], '%c') # datetime object
                project_list.append(date)
                if i >= 1:
                    break # break at row 2
    csvfile.close()
```

This stores the string 'as is', and I'm not sure what to do to convert it back into danish before I store it in the DB. The DB and Django are set up to work with danish chars.

If I try to decode it as utf.8 - I get a UnicodeDecodeError which reveals some more information.

```
01,01,Project Name: SAM_LOGIK_\x81rsm\xbfde_HD,,,Statistics as of: Sat Oct'
01 17:09:16 2016\r02,01,Project created: Tue Apr 12 09:10:16 2016,,,Last'
```

EDIT:

I found out that the strings in the csv are actually corrupted - and the application that created them (Avid Media Composer) at least consistently applies the same values for - Å-å-Æ-æ-Ø-ø

```
Å = \x81 unassigned in UTF8
å = Œ - u"\u0153" OE ligature
Æ = ® - chr(174)
æ = ¾ - chr(190)
Ø = » - chr(187)
ø = ¿ - chr(191)
```

I fixed it like this.

```
replacements = {'\x81':'Å','Œ':'å','®':'Æ','¾':'æ','¿':'ø','»':'Ø'}
with open(newest, 'rt', encoding='iso-8859-1') as csvfile:
        for i, row in enumerate(csvfile):
            if "Project Name:" in row:
                this = row.split(',')
                project_list.append("".join([replacements.get(c, c) for c in this[2][14:]]))
                if i >= 1:
                    break
            else:
                this = row.split(',')
                date = datetime.strptime(this[5][22:-1], '%c') # datetime object
                project_list.append(date)
                if i >= 1:
                    break # break at row 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try that

`row.decode('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8')`

And if you're use the "with" statement closing the file isn't necessary

Comment: This is correct when decoding - but the question changed in my edit.